# Brightcove Getting/Displaying current video title and description in HTML

Tags: javascript, brightcove

Can somebody please help me how to get Brigtcove current video title and description in HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Brightcove offers many examples on how this can be done accessing their API.  You can literally take the code straight from their example, input your read token, query their Media API with a video ID, and retrieve an Object with the Title and Description.  From there, you can just access the object and output the Title and Description.

Here's the Object reference for Brightcove's Media API.  The properties you're specifically looking for are called "name" and "longDescription": http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/javascript-media-api-examples

I'd highly recommend their "getting started" guide.  You can access code examples in here: http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/getting-started-media-api

Comment: I am looking for JS or JQuery to retrieve it and spit them out in a a div

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [smart player API](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/using-smart-player-api). The [getCurrentVideo()](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/smart-player-api/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html#getCurrentVideo) method returns information about the currently loaded video.

e.g.

```
videoplayer.getCurrentVideo(function (video) {
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = video.displayName;
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = video.shortDescription;
});
```